# encoding and decoding a string

Tags: unicode-string

I need to write an application that fist converts a string to unicode and then add 2 to the unicode value to create a new string.

Basically, if the input is: password is RhYxtz, then the output should look like: rcuuyqtf ku TjAzvb

the following code is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.print ("Enter text: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = scan.nextLine();

    int length = text.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i ++){
        char currentChar = text.charAt(i);
        int currentChar2 = currentChar+2;
        String s = String.format ("\\u%04x", currentChar2);
        System.out.println ("Encoded message: " + s);
    }

}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to convert the unicode back into a letter string and how to keep the format the same as the input. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Strings in Java are already in Unicode. You don't have to do any conversions, especially not if all your characters are in the ASCII range.

Comment: encoding and encoding a string ??? or encoding and decoding a string. You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.print ("Enter text: ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String text = scan.nextLine();
            int length = text.length();
            String s = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i ++){
        char currentChar = text.charAt(i);
        if (currentChar == ' '){
            s += currentChar;
        } else {
            s += (char) (currentChar + 2);
        }
    }
            System.out.println ("Encoded message: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding up to the answer: you can manipulate unicode characters using integers, as you did, but the data type will still be a char, not an int. Also a char can be cast into a String. ;-)

Comment: the output becomes rcuuyqtf"ku"Tj[zv| instead of rcuuyqtf ku TjAzvb. Is there any way to keep the whitespace and convert y and z to a and b?

Comment: @bt203 Certainly you can, but I am getting confused about what you want since this is not adding 2. To keep whitespace, use an if statement and `Character.isWhitespace()`. To have “cyclic overflow” on y and z, use another if statement.

Comment: @OleV.V. Those are special cases. Can you elaborate more on how to use if statements and the method you have mentioned?

Comment: @bt203 Added how to leave white spaces. Must add how to loop back to the first character if +2 passes the last (i.e. Z back to B). We should use the table values and a mathematical operation.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode code points can be gathered in java 8 as:

```
public static String encryped(String s) {
    int[] cps = s.codePoints()
            .mapToInt((cp) -> cp + 2)
            .toArray();
    return new String(cps, 0, cps.length);
}
```

or in a loop with codePointAt in earlier versions.

Java char (2 bytes) are UTF-16, and their int value is not always a Unicode symbol aka code point.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for US ASCII letters:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(length);

for(int i = 0; i < length; i ++){
    char currentChar = text.charAt(i);
    if (currentChar < 128 && Character.isLetter(currentChar)) {
        if (currentChar == 'y' || currentChar == 'z'
                || currentChar == 'Y' || currentChar == 'Z') {
            buf.append((char) (currentChar + 2 - 26));
        } else {
            buf.append((char) (currentChar + 2));
        }
    } else {
        buf.append(currentChar);
    }
}
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

Comment: I ought to, of course, declare the 2 and 26 named constants. Something like `static final int alphabetLength = ('z' - 'a') + 1;` Please consider marking the answer as accepted/correct/helpful, thx. :-)